# Nested Dictionary from List Formatting

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have 3 lists  - name1, name2, distance - using this code:

```
distdictionary = [{a: {b:c}} for a,b,c in zip(name1, name2, distance)]
```

I get a dictionary that looks like this:

```
[{'name1': {'name2': 737}},{'name1': {'name2': 717}}, {'name1': {'name2': 749}}....etc]
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
{'name1':{'name2': 737,'name2': 717, 'name2': 749}....etc]
```

name1 has a one-to-many relationship with name2 and distance and would be the start of the nested dictionary.

Adding some clarification/edits showing the lists:

```
name1    name2    distance  
-----    -----    --------   
John     Sarah    23  
John     Jane     64  
John     Anne     45  
David    Sarah    33  
David    Jane     56  
David    Anne     67  
Mike     Sarah    87  
Mike     Jane     24  
Mike     Anne     89
```

The nested dictionary should look like this:

```
{'John: {'Sarah': 23, 'Jane': 64, 'Anne': 45}, 
David: {'Sarah': 33, 'Jane': 56, 'Anne': 67},
Mike: {'Sarah': 87, 'Jane': 24, 'Anne': 89}}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help with this....

Comment: Your desired output is invalid in multiple ways. Please provide a [mre] including example input, full desired output, and full actual output. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go around that by creating a nested loop, and inside it have a temporary dictionary which is updated for each unique element in `name1`.

Find the example here below, which each of the `temp_dict1`, `temp_dict2` and `temp_dict3` are represented only by one temporary dictionary in the loop you should create. **Explanation:**

```
name1 =["John","John","John","David","David","David","Mike","Mike","Mike"]
name2 = ["Sarah","Jane","Anne","Sarah","Jane","Anne","Sarah","Jane","Anne"]
distance =[23,64,45,33,56,67,87,24,89]
temp_dict1 = {}
temp_dict2 = {}
temp_dict3 = {}
my_dict={}

temp_dict1[name2[0]]=distance[0]
temp_dict1[name2[1]]=distance[1]
temp_dict1[name2[2]]=distance[2]
my_dict[name1[0]]=temp_dict1

temp_dict2[name2[3]]=distance[3]
temp_dict2[name2[4]]=distance[4]
temp_dict2[name2[5]]=distance[5]
my_dict[name1[3]]=temp_dict2

temp_dict3[name2[6]]=distance[6]
temp_dict3[name2[7]]=distance[7]
temp_dict3[name2[8]]=distance[8]
my_dict[name1[6]]=temp_dict3



my_dict
```

The output is:

```
{'John': {'Sarah': 23, 'Jane': 64, 'Anne': 45},
 'David': {'Sarah': 33, 'Jane': 56, 'Anne': 67},
 'Mike': {'Sarah': 87, 'Jane': 24, 'Anne': 89}}
```

**The final solution is:**

```
name1 =["John","John","John","David","David","David","Mike","Mike","Mike"]
name2 = ["Sarah","Jane","Anne","Sarah","Jane","Anne","Sarah","Jane","Anne"]
distance =[23,64,45,33,56,67,87,24,89]
my_dict={}
start = 0
stop = 3
while start < len(name1):
    temp_dict = {}
    for i in range(start,stop):
        temp_dict[name2[i]]=distance[i]
        my_dict[name1[start]]=temp_dict
    start = start + 3
    stop = stop +3
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here:

`distdictionary = [{a: {b:c}} for a,b,c in zip(name1, name2, distance)]`

You are creating a list and not a dictionary, it might be confusing calling it dictionary.

Is the name1 column (which is a list) always following the same pattern? each name is repeated for three consecutive times?

Comment: Hi, yes, the name1 column is repeated a set number of times (in the example 3 times) each of the names in name2 are also repeated. Essentially the data is distances between all name1's (John, David, Mike) and all name2's (Sarah, Jane, Anne).